# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: null token

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm getting the callback didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: , however the data that is returned to me is empty.... so I don't know the device token.

Has anyone seen this before or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this is, I can't just read the NSData token into the NSString with UTF8 encoding and expect it to display the token.

This doesn't work:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken

NSLog(@"=== Device token: %@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

Whereas this does:

```
NSLog(@"data %@", _deviceToken);
```

Comment: My question is why doesn't it work. As it should work as indicated in your first example. Why is the deviceToken a special case?